# Can’t receive Firestore notifications since firebase_messaging ^14 upgrade

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I’m coming back to a project I haven’t worked on for a while so I decided to upgrade my outdated packages. I was running ***firebase_messaging: ^13.0.4*** and upgraded to ***^14.6.8***. If I return to the older version I receive notifications without issues. I assume that the plugin is getting initiated correctly because I’m able to get a token every time I start the app but I dont receive any messages when I test from the fcm console. Has anyone run into this issue when upgrading firebase_messaging?

```
Future initialize(BuildContext context) async {
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setAutoInitEnabled(true);

  final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  print(fcmToken)

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setAutoInitEnabled(true);

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) { 
    print(message.notification)
   });

}
```

Flutter Version: 3.13.2